# What may be the cause of my run time error while displaying my linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, runtime-error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Defining the structure

```
typedef struct node{
char name[20];
struct node *next;
}Node;

Node *head = NULL;

void insert ();

int main (){

Node *student1, *student2;
Node *walker;
int i;

head = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

for (i=0; i<3; i++) insert();

walker = head;

while(walker != NULL){
    printf ("%s\n", walker->name);
    walker = walker->next;  
}
return 0;
```

this loop works fine but adds some garbage at the end before crashing the program

```
}
```

Inserting the new node at the beggining

```
void insert(){
Node* nn;

nn = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

printf ("Name: ");
scanf ("%s", nn->name);

nn->next = head;
head = nn;

return;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to preallocate your head node; just leave it NULL and proceed into your insert() loop. As written you're `insert()` is invoked three times, yet you have four nodes. Hope that was what you wanted.

Comment: This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15084897/1057230) might be of some interest to you, I hope :-)

Comment: You may want to use static allocation for the head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `head->next` is not initialized, there is no null terminator at the end of your linked list. This leads to an undefined behavior.

```
/* In main() */

head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
head->next = NULL;
```